# Finding a distribution function for $Y=ax^2$

Tags: statistics, random-variables

X is a discrete random variable with a distribution function $F_x$ and PMF $P_X$. How can I find the distribution function of $Y = ax^2$, a $\neq$ 0.

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you ask yourself the probabilities. For simplicity let just assume $ a > 0 $.

What is the probability of Y to be 0? It is exactly the probability X = 0, right?
So $ P(Y = 0) = P(X = 0) $.

What is the probability of Y to be -1? It is impossible because that would require $ x^2 = \frac{-1}{a} $, but $ x $ is real. So $ P(y = -1) = 0 $ and so is for all negative values.

What is the probability of Y to be 4a? The would be the probability for $ (X = 2) $ plus the probability $ (X = -2) $. So we have

$ P(Y = 4a) = P(X = 2) + P(X = -2) $

Now you should have the idea how to compute the PMF for Y, the CMF is simply the running sum of it.